# Registrar repositorio en AppServiceProvider (error no encuentra clase)

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Estoy probando con los Interfaces y Repositorios en Laravel y no consigo que funcione. Lo he montado todo para el ejecutar me salta un error de que no encuentra la clase (el repositorio).

Interface

```
namespace app\Repositories;

interface ListaInterface
{
    public function listaHoy();

}
```

Repositorio

```
namespace app\Repositories;

use App\Models\Lista;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;


class SqlListaRepository implements ListaInterface{
    
    public function listaHoy()
    {
        return Lista::with('creador')
        ->where('listas.pagada', '=', "false")
        ->where('listas.created_at', '>=', date('Y-m-d'))
        ->orderByDesc('listas.created_at')
        ->get();     
    }
...
```

Controlador

```
namespace app\Http\Controllers;
use app\Repositories\ListaInterface;
class ListaController extends Controller
{
    protected $miListaRepository;
    
    /*
    * Para validar que todas las rutas necesitan estar logeadas para acceder.
    *
     */
    public function __construct(ListaInterface $repository){
        $this->miListaRepository = $repository;
    }
...
```

En AppServiceProvider

```
namespace app\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use app\Repositories\ListaInterface;
use app\Repositories\SqlListaRepository;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(ListaInterface::class, SqlListaRepository::class);
        
    }
...
```

¿Alguna idea de por qué me salta error de Target class [app\Repositories\SqlListaRepository] does not exist.?

Comment: Prueba poniendo en mayúscula App: `use App\Repositories\ListaInterface;` (en todas las clases donde estás haciendo `use`)

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Gracias! Por lo visto era eso, gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al indicar el namespace de una clase que está bajo el directorio `app/`, el namespace para ese directorio va con la primer letra en mayúscula, mismo que el nombre del directorio esté en minúsculas, pues así se lo está especificando en el archivo [composer.json](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/22626b5701cc7557d4bd45a6af5730027fc4a061/composer.json#L38) que trae Laravel por defecto:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        //...
    }
},
```

[psr-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) es un standard PHP que por convención usa Laravel. En [este enlace](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4) encontrarás más detalles, pero esencialmente se trata de la asignación de un namespace a un directorio en el sistema de archivos.

Laravel, usa esto para garantizar que sus clases se puedan encontrar en el sistema de archivos.

Entonces, el problema que lanza la excepción:

> Target class [app\Repositories\SqlListaRepository] does not exist.

Es porque cuando indicas el namespace de la clase SqlListaRepository, estás poniendo `app` en minúsculas:

```
use app\Repositories\SqlListaRepository;
```

y no hay un namespace con ese nombre, sino que se ha mapeado a `App`.
Por lo que para resolverlo, cambia el namespace a:

```
use App\Repositories\SqlListaRepository;
```